# Tesseract:Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract, tess4j

**Failed loading language 'ara' Tesseract couldn't load any languages!**

I want to use arabic with *tesseract*
But when i add `ara.traineddata` in tessdata folder and without result

i use Windows 10 and Java

the solution i find is : i download another ara.traineddata and add it into my tessdaata project and it works

Comment: any information helps, could you maybe supply a screenshot?

Comment: i dont know how to add a picture here sorry . but my question is there any problem with arabic language ? because i tried english and chinnes and its worked but with arabic  programme say that he couldn't load any language ("ara") i use tess4j 4.0.2

Comment: the debug message contains the location to where should ara.tessdata  be placed. Put it there.

Answer (score 0):

just create a folder in any directory you want and put the language file in there.

this worked for me:
ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
instance.setDatapath("C:\Users\Tux\Documents\tessdata");